# How to select the min/max element in an array using comparator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to find the largest element in an array. For example, finding the person with the highest salary. I can sort the array using a salary comparator, but it is inefficient. What is the simplest and best way to do this?

For reference, I can do this in Python as follows.

```py
heapq.nlargest(1, [array_of_whatever], comparator)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```js
const maxBy = (comparator, array) =>
    array.reduce((acc, val) => comparator(acc, val) > 0 ? acc : val);

const employees =
    [ { name: "Alice",   salary: 1000 }
    , { name: "Bob",     salary: 2000 }
    , { name: "Charlie", salary: 1500 }
    ];

const salaryComparator = (a, b) => a.salary - b.salary;

const max = maxBy(salaryComparator, employees);

console.log(max);
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, if you found my answer helpful you should upvote it by clicking on the upwards pointing triangle. In addition, if you found that my answer solves your problem and is the best answer amongst all the other answers then you should click on the tick mark next to the answer to mark it so.